# Time between rainfalls is exponentially distributed with $\lambda=1 ~\mbox{month}$. Probability that the longest time > 3 months in a 10 year period?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution, poisson-process

[image]

I am trying to solve part (c) of the problem above. I don't know how to solve it using the extreme value distribution, so I tried a Poisson process approach:

Let $N\sim\mbox{Pois}(120)$ be the number of heavy rainfalls over the next 10 years. Let $T_i\sim\mbox{Exp}(1)$ be the time (in months) between the $(i-1)$st and the $i$th heavy rainfall for $1\leq{}i\leq{}N$ (where it is understood that the "$0$th heavy rainfall" is just the start time, whether or not there is any rainfall at that time). All the $T_i$s
are iid. Then the desired probability is:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty{}P(\mbox{max time with \(k\) heavy rainfalls in \(10\) years > \(3\) months})*P(N=k)$$

Now it should be clear from the definition of $N$ that:

$$P(N=k)=\frac{e^{-120}120^k}{k!}$$

The probability I am less sure about is $p(k)\equiv{}P(\mbox{max time with \(k\) heavy rainfalls in \(10\) years > \(3\) months})$. The "max time" term refers to the maximum of the following times:

1. The time from the starting time to the time of the first heavy rainfall which occurs within 10 years from the starting time (for $k\geq1$).
2. The $k-1$ times between the $k$ heavy rainfalls which occur within 10 years from the starting time (for $k\geq2$).
3. The time from the $k$th heavy rainfall which occurs within 10 years from the starting time to the time exactly 10 years from the starting time (for $k\geq0$). Note that the "$0$th heavy rainfall" is just the start time, whether or not there is any rainfall at that time.

Now it should be clear that $p(k)=1$ for all $0\leq{}k\leq{}39$ since if the period of $120$ months is subdivided into less than 40 intervals then at least one of those intervals must be longer than 3 months, and if there are exactly 40 intervals then the only way for none of those intervals to be longer than 3 months is if they are all exactly 3 months long (the probability of which is $0$). On the other hand, for all $k\geq40$ we have $p(k)=1-q(k)$ where:

$$q(k)\equiv{}P(\mbox{max time with \(k\) heavy rainfalls in \(10\) years < \(3\) months})$$
$$=P(T_1<3,\ldots,T_k<3|117<T_1+\cdots+T_k<120)$$

I am not sure how to proceed further, however, since the condition $117<T_1+\cdots+T_k<120$ means that the $T_i$s are no longer independent. Does anybody know if it is possible to get something useful out of the expression above? I simulated this problem using R and after running the simulation a million times I got $0.999089$ as the desired probability, but I am wondering if it is possible to get this answer numerically. I have posted the R code below:

```
n <- 1000000 # number of trials

trials <- replicate(n,0)

for (i in 1:n){
    times <- c()
    
    while (sum(times)<120){
        time <- rexp(1,1)
        if (time > (120-sum(times))) break
        else times <- c(times,time)
    }
    
    max <- max(max(times),(120-sum(times)))
    
    if (max>3) trials[i] <- 1
}

mean(trials)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that $p(k)$ is a probability that is *conditional on the number of heavy rainfalls in a 120 month period.* This isn't explicit in your post. If you set $X_j=T_1+\dots +T_j$ for each $j$, it is known that the joint distribution of $(X_1,...,X_k)$ has the same distribution as $(U_{(1)},...,U_{(k)})$ where $U_j\sim \mathcal{U}\left([0,120]\right)$ are iid *when you condition on the* # *of arrivals.* This suggests to me that your approach of using the total law of probability won't be very fruitful as the problem is setting you up to use the extreme value distribution outlined in (b).

Comment: The problem is that the extreme value distribution derivation in (a) assumes the independence of a fixed number of exponential random variables, whereas in (c) there is the underlying assumption that the sum of a fixed number of exponential random variables is less than some value, so independence can no longer be assumed. This is why I don't know how to make use of (a) and (b) in order to solve (c).